# Python - Lists checking if something has been randomised already

Tags: python, list

Okay, so I am creating a program in python and basically it is a troubleshooting program for mobile phone users, it's very basic as of now, and I am in the situation where I am creating a list for the questions to be asked.

I will use the random module to randomise a string from the troubleshooting questions list, but I don't want it to randomise the first question in the list, then the first question in the list again.

So the real question; how do I check if the randomised string has already been randomised and if it has I want my program to randomise another string from the list, and if it has already been said then randomise another, if not use that string, etcetera.

Note: This program is no where near complete, I literally just started this now, so I am calling the function at the end so I can run the program at different times to see if it works.

```
import random

Questions = [
            'Has your phone gotten wet?', 'Have you damaged your screen?', 'Is the phone at full battery?',
            'Has your phone been dropped?', ' Does the mobile phone turn itself off?', 'Does the device keep crashing',
            'Does the phone keep freezing?', 'Can you not access the internet on your phone?', 'Is the battery draining quickly?',
            'Can you not access certain files on your phone?'
            ]
Solutions = [
            'Put your mobile phone inside of a fridge, it sounds stupid but it should work!', 'Try turning your device on and off',
            'Visit your local mobile phone store and seek help'
        ]
def PhoneTroubleshooting():
    print('Hello, welcome to the troubleshooting help section for your mobile phone.\n'
            'This troubleshooting program is going to ask you a series of questions, to determine the issue with your device.')
    answer = print(random.choice(Questions))
    if answer == 'yes':
            print('Okay, I have a solution', random.choice(Solutions))

    else: print('Okay, next problem')

PhoneTroubleshooting()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of choosing a single random element at a time, you should randomize the entire list using [`shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.shuffle), then iterate over that.  i.e.

```
random.shuffle(Questions)   # This shuffles `Questions` in-place

print(Questions[0])
...
```

Note, however, that you likely want to keep both of your lists coordinated -- i.e. you still want your answers to match your questions, so you should randomize the indices instead of the values:

```
inds = range(len(Questions))
random.shuffle(inds)
print(Questions[inds[0]])
...
print(Answers[inds[0]])
```

Comment: If there is a 1:1 relationship between solutions and questions, one could also argue in favor of a list of (question, solution)-tuples.

Comment: How would that work in my code though? I'm not quite sure I understand

Comment: So I tried it out and I keep getting a TypeError for 'range' object does not support item assignment

Comment: @Thom9son, then you are probably using Python3. Try `inds = list(range(len(Questions)))`

Comment: The only issue I have with this is, I have rearranged the positioning of the strings in the list myself, so that for example in Questions[0], this question has the correct answer of Solutions[0], so the answers line up with the questions but I'm still getting a random solution each time, help?

Comment: @Thom9son that was the point of the second half of my answer --- you should shuffle the indices instead, and then use the same index for both questions and answers